# Kali linux booting error after upgrade

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I was trying to install jdk since I needed to use javafx packages, so I uninstalled open jdk since mine did not have the javafx packages.

I then tried to install the jdk but then there were no repositories probably because I had edited my `sources.list`, which I then added the right ones.

So I did a `distro-upgrade` which took like 4hrs then suddenly stopped.

I restarted my computer and the boot process took a long time but stops with this error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start update utmp about System Runlevel Changes
See 'systemct1 status systemd-utmp-runlevel.service' for details
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching on the world wide web i found the following solution:

Press alt + f2 to login into a separate terminal session.

Then

sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session

sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session

reboot

The following link can provide additional information:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?31257-No-Boot-system-hang-on-quot-Started-Update-UTMP-about-System-Runlevel-Changes-quot